# Html Button Not working in IE,But work in other browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer

How to work in internet explore. It's work in other Browser.But won't work in IE.

```
<div class="cashbook_wrapper">
     <a href="new_reept.html">
         <input name="" type="button" value="New Receipt" class="btn" />
     </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. The [content model of an `<a>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) is:

> Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

Your input is interactive content.

If you want a link, then use a link (not a link and a button). If you want it to look like a button, then use CSS.

Comment: could give any example

Comment: There are [lots out there already](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+style+link+to+look+like+button&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+style+link+to+look+like+button&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i58.9437j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

You are using button inside link button.
Use button or use link to do this.
You can use  to send on new page

```
<form action="new_reept.html">
</form>
```

Now use submit button inside this not simple button

```
<input name="" type="submit" value="New Receipt" class="btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a button as a link turn it into a form. However this is kind of bad practice. Why not just use a link?

```
<div class="cashbook_wrapper">
    <form action="new_reept.html">
        <input type="submit" value="New Receipt" class="btn" />
    </form>
</div>
```